# AWS Gamekit - Could not create resources Identity And Authentication feature

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, unreal-engine4

I am new to AWS Gamekit as I am trying to create the resource Identity and Authentication but it gives me this Error in Unreal Engine:

```
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [@22920]~ Plugin settings file loaded from C:/Users/najb1/OneDrive/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject2/myproject2/saveInfo.yml
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ CreateStack Successful; StackId: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:333725018856:stack/gamekit-dev-myproject2-main/2144b610-e041-11ec-845e-0ae2abc8cfd3
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ Creating stack resources for stack: gamekit-dev-myproject2-main
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: gamekit-dev-myproject2-main | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: User Initiated
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: ApiGatewayLoggingRole | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: EmptyS3BucketOnDeleteLambdaRole | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: Resource creation Initiated
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: RestApi | CREATE_COMPLETE: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: RootGetMethod | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: Resource creation Initiated
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: MainRequestValidator | CREATE_COMPLETE: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: RestApiDeployment | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: MainDeploymentStage | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: EmptyS3BucketOnDeleteLambda | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: UsagePlan | CREATE_FAILED: Resource creation cancelled
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: RemoveLambdaLayersOnDeleteLambda | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: ApiGatewayLogGroup | DELETE_COMPLETE: 
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ gamekit-dev-myproject2-main: RemoveLambdaLayersOnDeleteLambdaRole | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS: 
LogAwsGameKit: Error: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ CloudFormation creation failed.
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ ~GameKitFeatureResources()
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C21EF70@22920]~ AwsApiInitializer::Shutdown(): Not shutting down (count: 6)
LogAwsGameKit: Error: FeatureResourceManager::CreateOrUpdateResources() Creating/Updating stack failed. : 0x3f2
LogAwsGameKit: Display: AwsGameKitSessionManagerWrapper::ReloadConfig(myproject2/dev/)
LogAwsGameKit: Display: Copied config from C:/Users/najb1/OneDrive/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject2/myproject2/dev/awsGameKitClientConfig.yml to ../../../../../../Users/najb1/OneDrive/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject2/Content/GameKitConfig/awsGameKitClientConfig.yml
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [@22920]~ GameKitSessionManager::ReloadConfigFile()
LogAwsGameKit: Error: FeatureResourceManager::CreateOrUpdateResources() for Main feature: Could not create resources. : 0x3f2. Please find more details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamekit/latest/DevGuide/versions.html#versions-knownissues
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C221EE0@22920]~ ~GameKitFeatureResources()
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C221EE0@22920]~ AwsApiInitializer::Shutdown(): Not shutting down (count: 5)
LogAwsGameKit: FeatureResourceManager::GetResourcesStackStatus()
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C220DA0@22920]~ AwsApiInitializer::Initialize(): Already initialized (count: 4)
LogAwsGameKit: Display: [000001F43C220DA0@22920]~ GameKitFeatureResources()
LogAwsGameKit: Display: Error: FeatureResourceManager::CreateOrUpdateResources() for Main feature: Could not create resources.
```

I think the problem is caused by a role not being specified. But I can't figure out which one. Could anyone be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got this using eu-west-2 (yours looks like us-east-1). Changed the environment region to us-west-2 (or try whichever else) and there were no problems.

Also, noticed in aws GameLift they don't offer matchmaking in certain regions, etc., so keep these region limitations in mind.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed an issue of region